# Can someone with only a master's degree promoted to a permanent full-time faculty at a two-year college?

Tags: teaching, lecturer, community-college, instructor

Long story short, I am a master's graduate it statistics, and I recently applied to enrol in a local two-year college program to land a job in my rural hometown (I prefer to have a career in my rural town than in a bigger city, due to personal health and other circumstances). The admission secretary at the local two-year college saw my educational credentials and forwarded my transcripts to the dean of the two-year college's university transfer program. The dean called me on my cell and wanted to interview me for a part-time instructor position. I passed the interview and I will be start teaching introductory university math/stat courses at the two-year college in near future.

As a person who is just starting out in the two-year college teaching career, I am wondering whether the fact that I only have a master's degree in statistics and not Ph.D. would later prevent me from becoming a permanent full-time faculty at this two-year college. The dean of the university transfer program has a Ph.D. in medicine, and I see some other faculty members who have Ph.D. in their teaching disciplines. Primarily, this college offers two-year programs in trades, social work, and nursing, and this college does not offer any bachelor's degree program (although they do offer a transfer program to 4-year university).

Do two-year rural colleges like this promote instructors with a master's degree to a permanent full-time faculty if they teach well? or does such a promotion typically only restricted to instructors with Ph.D.? I am located in Canada.

Thank you,

Comment: I think that, in the US, at least and likely Canada, this is a purely local question. You can ask any college what their requirements are for promotion and whether there are any exceptions if they are strict. I think you will get different answers from different places. For 4 year colleges and universities there may be more uniform requirements, but with some exceptions allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the faculty credentials at this institution and similar ones (in Canada). Their websites should provide this information. You can see whether any permanent faculty have only master's degrees.

After you have taught for a year, and presumably done a good job, you might ask the administration about the possibility of a permanent appointment.